# Bootstrap 3 submenu stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been having trouble with a bootstrap 3 flyout menu. (head-desk head-desk)
When a user clicks TILE #1 a menu appears. (LINK 1, LINK 2, etc.)

My hope is to hide the last submenu flyout when another menu option is clicked. i.e. click LINK 1 and it appears. Click LINK 2 and it appears while LINK 1 one disappears (and vise/verse). This way only one submnu shows at a time. As you can see from the screen shot below, the submenus are stacking.

[image: Screeny]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhpvT.png)
Here is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- toggle="dropdown"><img src="01_tile.png" width="300">
        </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="flyout" tabindex="-1" href="#">LINK 1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a class="flyout" tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">Calorie</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">A site</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">96</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">45</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="flyout" tabindex="-1" href="#">LINK 2 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">Action</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">Information</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">Dear</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">Special</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">LINK 3</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">LINK 4</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">LINK 5</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="https://www.anysite.com" target="_blank">LINK 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-submenu a.flyout').on("click", function(e){
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bootstrap from 3.0 or 3.1 do not support submenu for dropdown so You must create Your own by JS and CSS.

Comment: I did so and it works pretty well. Now if I could just get them to toggle!

Comment: Just wanted to pass this along for anyone with similar issues. It really helped me. Thanks A. Vasily. [https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-submenu/](https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-submenu/)